# I want full div without container-fluid but not change container width and structure?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want full `div` without `container-fluid` but not change container width i want container width fix because my another `div` want in container so. Also structure will not change i want this structure.

```css
.main {
   padding: 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="col-12">
           <div class="half">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</div>
           <div class="full">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not duplicate it's not correct answer for me i want fix width of container not change container width

Comment: you have solution without change container width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this it will be worked fine for you, i have added some CSS

```css
.main {
   padding: 100px 0;
}

.full{
  background:red;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  left: 50%;
  padding:0 25px 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="col-12">
           <div class="half">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</div>
           <div class="full">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```